# Convex hull of the intersection of nonconvex sets

Tags: convex-polytopes, convexity, computational-geometry

I have a set $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ which is the intersection of $d$ domains $D_i$ given by $f(x_{i}) \leq x_{i+1} \leq g(x_{i})$ for two functions $f$ and $g$.

I want to find the convex hull of $D$. Since the $D_i$'s are not necesseraly convex, I cannot produce such convex hull by intersection of the convex hulls of the $D_i$'s.

Is there any algorithm that allows me to compute the convex hull of $D$, $CH(D)$, as the intersection of halfspaces in $\mathbb{R}^d$?